# Building dynamic .framework libraries for distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bazel

How do I use Bazel to build a .framework library using swift. Is there any examples on how this can be done. I have a project that successfully builds, but it is missing the modulemap, .swiftmodule directories and bridging header